# Implementing a Custom Error page on an ASP.Net website

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I have an ASP.Net website and I want to use a custom error page. I put the following code in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

The problem is when i go to a URL that does not exist is still uses the 404 error page specified in IIS Manager.

**Question:** How can I make it use the error.aspx page I have created? Why do the settings in IIS Manager override the web.config?

Comment: I am using IIS 6 on Server 2003.

Answer (score 33):

Try this way, almost same.. but that's what I did, and working.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="apperror.aspx">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
          <error statusCode="500" redirect="500.aspx" />
       </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

or try to change the 404 error page from IIS settings, if required urgently.

Comment: If I have the <error> tag outside of the <customError> tags I get an error.

I have to put a closing </customError> tag after the error tags but it still does not work.

Comment: Got it working when I remembered to change `mode` to `On`

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to configure custom error pages for ASP.NET sites:

1. Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (the GUI)
2. web.config file

This article explains how to do each:

- [How To Set Up Custom Error Pages In IIS 7.5 With ASP.NET](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/)

**The reason your *error.aspx* page is not displaying might be because you have an error in your web.config. Try this instead:**

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="404" redirect="error.aspx"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You might need to make sure that `Error Pages` in **IIS Manager - Feature Delegation** is set to *Read/Write*:

[image: IIS Manager: Feature Delegation panel]

Also, this answer may help you configure the web.config file:

- [What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480006/what-is-the-difference-between-customerrors-and-httperrors/25088870#25088870)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150812092729/http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/
The link is outdated but we can still visit it thanks to the mighty Wayback machine

Answer (score 3):

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx" mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Code above is only for  "Page Not Found Error-404" if file extension is known(.html,.aspx etc)

Beside it you also have set Customer Errors for extension not known or not correct as

`.aspwx` or `.vivaldo`. You have to add `httperrors` settings in `web.config`

```
<httpErrors  errorMode="Custom"> 
       <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx"         responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

it must be inside the `<system.webServer>` `</system.webServer>`

Comment: Carefull setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true. See this post from hanselman: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.webServer>     
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="your page" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It's good to add a description to your answer for future reference

Answer (score -3):

Is it a spelling error in your closing tag ie:

```
</CustomErrors> instead of </CustomError>?
```